# How to specify Log4J 2.x config location?

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

Is there any way to specify Log4J 2.x `log4j2.xml` file location manually (like `DOMConfigurator` in Log4J 1.x), without messing with classpath and system properties?

Comment: You can use *log4j2.component.properties* for this purpose. Short explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59190560/443259)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You could use the static method `#initialize(String contextName, ClassLoader loader, String configLocation)` (see source [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/xref/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/Configurator.html#43)) in `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator`.
(You can pass null for the class loader.)

Be aware that this class is not part of the public API so ***your code may break with any minor release***.

For completeness, you can also specify the location of the configuration file with this system property:

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=path/to/log4j2.xml
```

Comment: This is no simple way because Configurator (and others) can be extended (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/extending.html)

Comment: Where do I call the ```Configurator.initialize() ``` in my project? I am asking it because I am doing it in a static block and Log4j is logging that it does not found the file before my code run.

Answer (score 10):

For log4j version 2.12.1, you can find how to reconfigure log4j2 [here](http://For%20log4j%20version%202.12.1,%20you%20can%20find%20how%20to%20reconfigure%20log4j2%20on%20https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#reconfig_from_code%20Below%20is%20an%20example).

Below is an example

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;

File file = new File("C:\\Path for Windows OS\\yourConfig.xml");
    
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
context.setConfigLocation(file.toURI());
    
Logger log  = LogManager.getLogger(YourClass.class);
```

It seems to me that way of configuring log4j2 is changing with new releases, so you should be aware of that.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using log4j2 and properties are in defined in log4j2.properties file then use this.

> -Dlog4j2.configurationFile=file:/home/atul/log4j2.properties

Comment: Is it `-Dlog4j2.conf..` or `-Dlog4j.conf..` like the other comment says?

Comment: If you are using log4j2 then my answer will help you.

Comment: Seems both ways do the job for log4j2.

Answer (score 8):

In Windows, be aware that you need to use a URI with the `log4j.configurationFile` property

```
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file://C:\path\to\log4j2.xml
```

Comment: I believe the system property accepts a normal file path (relative or absolute) as well as a URI.

Comment: It does not work. I got ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'org.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level' to TRACE to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.

Comment: I used "C:\\Users\\P....\\H............\\workspace\\P...........\\log4j2.properties" as the value for the system property "log4j.configurationFile" and it worked correctly. The double backslashes were needed by Java (internally they were converted to single backslashes). The dots were actually the correct letters in the path.

Comment: File URIs can have two or three slashes; both are syntactically correct but semantically different. Three slashes (equivalent to omitting “localhost” between the second and third slash) is used to access local files. Two slashes (as long as the host is not “localhost”) is used to access files in a remote system. Source : https://wiki.eclipse.org/File_URI_Slashes_issue

Answer (score 4):

Using the LoggerContext allows to [setConfigLocation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/LoggerContext.html#setConfigLocation%28java.net.URI%29).

```
File f = new File(this.logConfigFile);
URI fc = f.toURI();         
System.out.println("Loading logging config file: " + fc);
Logger l = (Logger) LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
l.getContext().setConfigLocation(fc);
```

or alternatively

```
LoggerContext.getContext().setConfigLocation(java.net.URI);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize like below as well

```
ConfigurationSource source = new ConfigurationSource(new FileInputStream(log4j file Path));
XmlConfiguration xmlConfig = new XmlConfiguration(source);
Logger logger = (Logger) LogManager.getLogger(); 
logger.getContext().start(xmlConfig);
```

**In each class you can get logger instance as below**

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ABC.class);
```

Comment: [org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger.html) has no getContext() method.

Answer (score 1):

Step: 1 - Get ready with your log4J.xml file with the appender details (Mostly under the resource folder)

Step: 2 - Following code should be added to the configuration class (In the previous log4J we had **PropertyConfigurator** and now we need to go with **LoggerContext**)

```
String log4JFilePath = "file path of your log4J.xml file";
LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext)LoggerManager.getContext(false);
File file = new File(log4JFilePath);
loggerContext.setConfigLocation(file.toURI());
```

Step: 3 - Add the following line to utilise the logger in any classes

```
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(yourClassName.class);

logger.info("log here");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

     Configurator.initialize(null, "src/main/config/log4j2.xml"); //path specify

     Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(APITestToolMain.class);
     logger.info("working");
    }
}
```

resource: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-change-log4j2-location

Answer (score 0):

```
void initializeLogger()
{      
    try
        {
            String basepath=checkpath();
            File f = new File(basepath+"\\config\\log4j2.properties");
            URI fc = f.toURI(); 
            LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
            context.setConfigLocation(f.toURI());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            errorlog="Unable to load logging property:";
            System.out.println(errorlog+": "+e.getMessage());
        }   
}
```

This is the way I initialize my log4j2 properties file from a different location, so what I simply do is to call the initializeLogger() method in my main method.

And it works perfectly.

Perhaps you need to see what the checkpath() blocks looks like, I added the function below.

```
String checkpath()
    {
        String parentpath="";
        try
        {
           URL url=getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
           File f=new File(url.toURI());
           parentpath=f.getParent();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //logger.error("unable to retrieve application parent path");
        }
        return parentpath;
    }
```