# How can I change the default location of log4j2.xml in Java Spring Boot?

Tags: java, log4j, spring-boot, log4j2

Log4j2 is working nicely with Spring Boot through the `log4j2.xml` configuration file in the root classpath, exactly as the documentation states.

When trying to move this file to a different location though, I'm not able to pass the new location to Spring at startup. From [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-custom-log-configuration):

> The various logging systems can be activated by including the
>   appropriate libraries on the classpath, and further customized by
>   providing a suitable configuration file in the root of the classpath,
>   or **in a location specified by the Spring Environment property
>   `logging.config`**.

I tried setting the new location with a Java system property

```
java -jar -Dlogging.config="classpath:/config/log4j2.xml" target/app.jar
```

or using an external `application.properties` containing the relevant property

```
logging.config=classpath:/config/log4j2.xml
```

But I am regularly greeted by the following error message.

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
```

Comment: Could you please confirm if `/config` is in the classpath? if you are using maven based project, put the xml file under `src/main/resources`

Comment: The `config` folder (package) is in the classpath, and it already contains `application.yml`, that is correctly picked up and succesfully used in the application.

Comment: Could you please put the xml file in `src/main/resources` and try so that we can narrow down the issue?

Comment: If I put the XML file in its right location, the classpath root (`src/main/java`), it works without problems. I'm not getting what we should check by putting the XML in the `src/main/resources` folder. What I want to be able to do is to put the log4j2.xml file wherever I want.

Comment: Since it is working fine when you put it in `src/main/java`, it means there is no problem with the configuration. If you want it to work irrespective of the location of the `log4j2.xml`, you have to make sure that the folder is in classpath. If you are using eclipse, `right click on the project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path` to set the classpath.

Comment: I found out the right way to include an external configuration file for Log4j2 is `mvn spring-boot:run -Dlogging.config="/path/to/file/test.xml"` (or similarly when using `java -jar`). Still, I've not been able to include a file already in the classpath at build time. I'm not sure that's actually possible.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As specified in the [Spring reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-custom-log-configuration), the `logging.config` property cannot be set among the application properties, as they are read after the logging has already been initialised.

The solution is to provide the path to the external logging configuration this way:

```
java -Dlogging.config='/path/to/log4j2.xml' -jar app-current.jar
```

Comment: There's another solution via the **log4j2.component.properties** file as described in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28349309/how-can-i-change-the-default-location-of-log4j2-xml-in-java-spring-boot/59190560#59190560) below which doesn't necessitate providing the config file name via system properties or command line parameters

Comment: From the documentation I read: `The various logging systems can be activated by including the appropriate libraries on the classpath and can be further customized by providing a suitable configuration file in the root of the classpath or in a location specified by the following Spring Environment property: logging.config.` The only exception is for ` logging from @PropertySources in Spring @Configuration file` which is dictated by initialization order. Hence, why "logging.config property cannot be set among the application properties"?

Comment: look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43907702/448078) answer

Answer (score 17):

As mentioned in the log4j2 documentation [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#config_location), you can include a file named `log4j2.component.properties` in your resources folder (or anywhere in the classpath) and inside that file, you can provide the name of the file location (or a new file name) like this:

```
log4j.configurationFile=path/to/log4j2.xml
```

or

```
log4j.configurationFile=classpath:log4j2-custom.xml (if the file is on the classpath)
```

You can alternatively provide the config file location via the `context-param` fields of `web.xml` as mentioned [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#config_location), but I haven't tried that option

(This works with Spring Boot too)

Answer (score 8):

The answer of [micpalmia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/592138/micpalmia) is absolutely correct.

I needed to put the configuration outside the classpath I didn't want to pass the config file as a parameter. So i put a very simple logging configuration in the classpath resources and had the spring boot application reconfigure logging upon start, like so:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... param) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Configurator.initialize(null, "config/log4j2.xml");
        // ...
    }
}
```

This approach has a significant disadvantage: The whole application boot process will not be logged as externally configured. But once the custom code is run the logger works as intended. While you may not, I find this to be a compromise I can live with.

Comment: Regarding the boot process, won't using both `-Dlog4j.configurationFile` and `-Dlogging.config` take care of this? (It does for me, but I'm not sure we have the same use case.)

Comment: Check this answer as well. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716556/how-to-specify-log4j-2-x-config-location)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem in my project, besides log4j2.xml I also need other config files in the class path.
Here is my 2 solutions that works:

Soluation 1 : Start spring boot application with org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher

```
java -classpath SpringBootProject.jar;./config org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

Solution 2:  Write a './config' class path entry in the MANIFEST.MF in the jar

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
               <Class-Path>./config/</Class-Path>
            </manifestEntries>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 2):

In case of property file:

> java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/path/to/log4j.properties -jar app.jar

To the command line works in Spring Boot 2. Don't forget to add **file:** before the path.

Answer (score 0):

I have working solution to set custom path or change existing file path for logging file. If you have configured log4j2.xml file, open it and see where you have to do one line change to config log file path.[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question was asking about the location of the log4j configuration file (log4j.xml) rather than the file for writing the log statements to

Comment: This also looks a whole lot like AnyPoint Studio and not a "normal" Java Application

Answer (score 0):

If you  try to rename the log4j2.xml file other than the default name. In order to load the file.
For a spring boot  application in application.properties file add below property
this would work

```
logging.config=classpath:logfilename.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this in Spring boot

```
 java -jar app.jar --logging.config=/path/to/log4j2.xml
```