# log4j : reconfigure twice

Tags: java, json, configuration, log4j

I want when my app starts to configure log4j with some default configuration.
Once the other configuration (non-log4j) is parsed I get the real file-path to the real log4j configuration.
Now I can fully configure log4j.

How would you do that. (java) ?

Also I prefer to use .json config file, if it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16716556/79450), it seems to be pretty complicated with log4j2 (which is what I assume you're using seeing as you're talking about using a JSON configuration file, which didn't exist in log4j 1.x as far as I know).

If you're willing to use an XML or properties log4j configuration and also step down to log4j 1.x, you can use [`PropertyConfigurator.configure(String)`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html#configure%28java.lang.String%29) or [`DOMConfigurator.configure(String)`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/DOMConfigurator.html#configure%28java.lang.String%29) depending on if you're using a properties or XML configuration file.