# spring boot use log4j2 and log4j2.xml not in resource

Tags: spring-boot, resources, log4j2

I use spring-boot and `log4j2`, how can my application not read `log4j2.xml` in resource folder. Read my custom location for the `log4j2.xml` file?

Comment: show your configurations and point to the stuff which is not working. Otherwise this question will not get any answer

Comment: you can just refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716556/how-to-specify-log4j-2-x-config-location